# Open ucanaccess/jackcess database in wildfly using iso-8859-1

Tags: character-encoding, wildfly, ucanaccess, jackcess

I have a connection to an MS Access 2000 database defined in wildfly 9.0.2. Works fine. Using the commandline UCanAccess, I run it with `-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859` in order to have national characters (Norwegian) displayed correctly, on Ubuntu. On OS X the commandline displays national characters correctly without any jre-option. However the Wildlfy instance is also running on OS X, and does not display national characters correct (currently they're just written to console in a simple test) Using UcanAccess-driver in any java-based sql client like DBeaver or SQLSquirrel "just works" when it comes to character set. However, querying the database via JPA and wildfly, the national characters are replaced with '?'.

So, there is a way to specify a praticular "opener" on the jdbc-url for Jackcess:

```
......mdb;jackcessOpener=ucaextension.JackcessWithCharsetISO88591Opener
```

where the "opener" looks like this:

```
public class JackcessWithCharsetISO88591Opener implements JackcessOpenerInterface {
    public Database open(File f, String pwd) throws IOException {
        DatabaseBuilder db = new DatabaseBuilder(f);
        db.setCharset(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
        try {
            db.setReadOnly(false);
            return db.open();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            db.setReadOnly(true);
            return db.open();
        }
    }
}
```

(yes, the exception handling should at least issue a warning.)

So I packaged this as a jar-file (maven), removed the old connection, driver and module definitions in wildfly. Then I added this jar-file, along with the others for the ucanaccess module (ucanaccess itself, hsqldb etc), recreated the driver and connection, now with the opener-parameter, and re-reployed the war using it. But wildfly complains:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ucaextension.JackcessWithCharsetISO88591Opener from [Module "com.ucanaccess:main" from local module loader @1060b431 (finder: local module finder @612679d6 (roots: /Users/jonmartinsolaas/Local/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules,/Users/jonmartinsolaas/Local/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules/system/layers/base))]
```

So clearly the url-parameter has been picked up, but the class is not found, even though it is deployed along with the other jars for the driver. The class is actually in the jar-file. But do I need to reference it from any other MANIFEST.INF classpath in the other jars or something?

Comment: Specifying ISO-8859-1 as the character set should not really be necessary. Access has stored text as Unicode for many years now. If you open the database in Access itself does the text appear correctly? If so, what version of Access is it?

Comment: It is Access 2000, the characters appear correct in Access, and in UCanAccess commandline running with jvm-option -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859 on Ubuntu. On OS X this option to UCanAccess commandline is not needed. The Wildfly instance I use now is running on OS X and does not display national chars correctly.

Comment: *"the Wildlfy instance is also running on OS X, and does not display national characters correct (currently they're just written to console in a simple test)"* - Perhaps the OS X console is simply misleading you by displaying some Unicode characters as `?`. I've seen the Windows command prompt do that. If that's the case then you should just retrieve the text as Unicode and ensure that your application can handle the Unicode characters correctly.

Comment: @Gord, yup, testing it properly, eg. displaying data in the gui of my app works just fine, national characters available and all. It was just the logging output shown in IntelliJ console that was "off". Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case, it seems, is that various consoles doesn't show the national characters. That, and the fact that I actually have to specify charset running on the ubuntu commandline, led me to believe there was a problem, and actually displaying data in the browser and not in the logging console showed just that. No need for a jackcess "opener" for a specific character set.